# How can Subclass a ComboBox and implement ICommandSource since ComboBox dosen't have Command property in WindowsUI 3?

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

Implement ICommand to create a command type to perform the task after DropDownOpened, SelectionChanged for use in MVVM.

There is this article for WPF but it does not work in WinUI 3 App
ComboBox.DropDownOpened MVVM how to?

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom control like this.

**CustomComboBox.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ComboBoxTests;

public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DropDownOpenedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(DropDownOpenedCommand),
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(CustomComboBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public CustomComboBox()
    {
        this.DropDownOpened += CustomComboBox_DropDownOpened;
    }

    private void CustomComboBox_DropDownOpened(object? sender, object e)
    {
        DropDownOpenedCommand?.Execute(null);
    }

    public ICommand DropDownOpenedCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(DropDownOpenedCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(DropDownOpenedCommandProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Instead of creating a custom control, you can also just use the **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed** NuGet package to bind a command to an event, and the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** NuGet package for MVVM implementation.

**NuGet packages**:

- [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors)
- [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet)

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="ComboBoxTests.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:local="using:ComboBoxTests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">

        <!--  Custom control example  -->
        <local:CustomComboBox
            x:Name="CustomComboBoxControl"
            Grid.Row="0"
            DropDownOpenedCommand="{x:Bind ViewModel.DoSomethingCommand}"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <!--  Behaviors package example  -->
        <ComboBox
            x:Name="ComboBoxControl"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DropDownOpened">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.DoSomethingCommand}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ComboBox>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using ComboBoxTests.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ComboBoxTests;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ComboBoxTests.ViewModels;

public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<string> items = new()
    {
        "Item A",
        "Item B",
        "Item C",
    };

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string selectedItem = "Item A";

    [RelayCommand]
    private void DoSomething()
    {
    }

    // This will be called when "SelecteItem" is changed.
    // So, when "SelectionChanged" occurs.
    partial void OnSelectedItemChanged(string value)
    {
    }
}
```